# Detect if my extension is in control of proxy settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy

My extension  takes control of a user proxy settings.However if the user has recently install another proxy/vpn extension then that extension has control of the user proxy settings instead of mine.

In case my extension don't have priority i will then send a message to the user

How can i detect if my extension is in control of proxy settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`chrome.proxy.settings`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy#property-settings), you could call `chrome.proxy.settings.get(object details, function callback)` to get the chrome browser setting info, and the parameter for the callback is `object details`, you could check `details.levelOfControl`, its values is

> enum of "not_controllable", "controlled_by_other_extensions", "controllable_by_this_extension", or "controlled_by_this_extension"

```
chrome.proxy.settings.get(function(details) {
    if(details.levelOfControl === 'controlled_by_other_extensions') {
        // 
    }
});
```